# Parse text/json file python, get multiple lines to single line

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

A text/json file would be in this format. I would like to parse it and get an output like the one below.

#text/json file format:

```
stringA = {
  url     = "$foo"
  version = "v0.foo"
}

stringB = {
  url     = "$bar"
  version = "v0.bar
}

stringC = {
  url     = "$cat"
  version = "v0.cat"
}
```

output format:

```
stringA $foo v0.foo
stringB $bar v0.bar
stringC $cat v0.cat
```